# Nested getline creates stays at first value

Tags: c++

I want to read values from a .csv file and since I'm new to c++ I want to keep things as simple (simple for me that is) as possible.

The date looks like this

```
00,-00.90,00.13,-00.04,-00.84,-00.89,00.11,-02.18,-00.79,....
```

The code is this

```
ifstream ver("file.csv");

string zeile;

while (std::getline(ver, zeile, '\n'))
{
    string spalte;

    std::cout << zeile << endl;

    while (std::getline(istringstream(zeile), spalte, ','))
    {
        std::cout << spalte;            
    }
}
```

The outcome is, that `std::cout << spalte` always return 00, instead of each value.

When I change the first while to `while (std::getline(ver, zeile, ','))`, the values are separated nicely, but thats not what I want.

I know there are many other and probably easier/better ways to do this, but I would like to understand why this in not working.

I tried

Comment: You instance the `std::istringstream` in each iteration new. Hence, it starts everytimes at begin of `zeile`. You should move this to top of loop.

Comment: Your are right, Thank You!